# add inset graph in sas?

Tags: sas, scatter

I'm wondering if there's a way to add an inset graph in another graph in SAS. I see quite a bit of stuff about adding text insets into a figure, but nothing about a graph. I am making scatterplots with, for example, leaf mass on the x-axis, and leaf area on the y. The slope of the line tells me the ratio of these two quantities, which is specific leaf area. This is also important, so I want to be able to show that, as well. But since its not new information (relative to the scatterplots), I don't want to make another figure since it will basically show the same thing, just in different ways. But if I had it as an inset, that would be okay.

I use SAS 9.4 at school and SAS university edition at home. Here's the code I have for the scatterplot:

```
proc template; define statgraph Graph; 
dynamic _MASS_PER_LEAF _SA_PER_LEAF _GROUP _LT_MASS_PER_LEAF _LT_SA_PER_LEAF _GROUP2;
begingraph / designwidth=500 designheight=819 attrpriority=none DataSymbols=(circle x circle x circle x) DataContrastColors=(CX0000FF CX0000FF CXCC0033 CXCC0033 CX639A21 CX639A21) 
DataLinePatterns=(1 2 1 2 1 2);

legendItem type=marker name='Beech' / label = 'Beech' markerattrs=(color=CX0000FF symbol=circlefilled) ;
legendItem type=marker name='Red Maple' / label = 'Red Maple' markerattrs=(color=CXCC0033 symbol=circlefilled) ;
legendItem type=marker name='Sugar Maple' / label = 'Sugar Maple' markerattrs=(color=CX639A21 symbol=circlefilled) ;
legendItem type=marker name='Calcium' / label = 'Calcium' markerattrs=(color=black symbol=circle) ;
legendItem type=marker name='Control' / label = 'Control' markerattrs=(color=black symbol=x) ;

layout lattice / rowdatarange=data columndatarange=union rows=2 rowgutter=10 columngutter=10 rowweights=(1.0 1.0);
layout overlay / yaxisopts=( label=('Average surface area per leaf (cm^2)'));
scatterplot x=_MASS_PER_LEAF y=_SA_PER_LEAF / group=_GROUP name='scatter' markerattrs=(size=11 weight=bold );
        regressionplot x = mass_per_leaf y = sa_per_leaf / group = group; 
entry halign=left 'Green leaves' / valign=top; 
  endlayout;
  layout overlay / yaxisopts=( label=('Averge surface area per leaf (cm^2)'));
     scatterplot x=_LT_MASS_PER_LEAF y=_LT_SA_PER_LEAF / group=_GROUP2     
name='scatter2' markerattrs=(size=11 weight=bold );
regressionplot x = mass_per_leaf y = sa_per_leaf / group = group; 
entry halign=left 'Senesced leaves' / valign=top;
     discretelegend 'Beech' 'Red Maple' 'Sugar Maple' 'Calcium' 'Control' /
        opaque=false 
        border=true 
        halign=right 
        valign=bottom 
        displayclipped=true 
        down=3
        order=columnmajor 
        location=inside;

endlayout;
  columnaxes;
     columnaxis / label=('Average mass per leaf (g)');
  endcolumnaxes;
endlayout;
endgraph;
end;
run;

proc sgrender data=WORK.CALCIUM template=Graph;
dynamic _MASS_PER_LEAF="'MASS_PER_LEAF'n" _SA_PER_LEAF="'SA_PER_LEAF'n" _GROUP="GROUP" _LT_MASS_PER_LEAF="'LT_MASS_PER_LEAF'n" _LT_SA_PER_LEAF="'LT_SA_PER_LEAF'n" _GROUP2="GROUP";

run;
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Why not provide some sample data so that others can run the code you have supplied?  You're much more likely to get some help that way.

Comment: Is there a way to add data as an attachment or something? Or should I just add it to my original post? This is my first time asking a question here, so apologies for naivete.

Comment: Typically people will use one of the datasets from the `sashelp` libname as these come provided on all SAS installations.